# モーダルダイアログの子ウィンドウから親ウィンドウの関数を呼び出す方法

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

cakePHP2 + mysql + bootsrap3 でサイトを構築しています。

親ウィンドウから、入力ウィンドウとして子ウィンドウ①を開き、
必要なIDがなければ生成するための子ウィンドウ②を立ち上げてID登録をして
子ウィンドウ①に返す　といった処理を組もうとしています。

その際に、どのようにすれば子ウィンドウ①から子ウィンドウ②に値を返せるかが
わかりません。

お手数ですが、ご教授下さい。
よろしくお願い致します。

```
--------- 親View -------------
<div id="Modal1" class="modal fade"></div>
<div id="Modal2" class="modal fade"></div>

<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
  $('#Modal1').html(data);
  $('#Modal1').modal('show');
});
</script>

------子ウィンドウ①（Modal1）----------
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
  $('#Modal2').html(data);
  $('#Modal2').modal('show');

  initialize();

  function hoge(test){
    alert("これを実行したい");
    $("#test").val(test);
    initialize();
  }

  function initialize(){
    //初期処理
  }
});
</script>

------子ウィンドウ②（Modal2）----------
<script language="JavaScript">
$(function() {
  //子ウィンドウ①の関数を実行したい
  hoge(1);
});
</script>
```

Comment: jQuery UI の[モーダルダイアログ](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)を使ったモーダルダイアログということなら単にHTMLの一部をダイアログフォームとして使っているだけなので、通常のHTMLDOMと同じように値を取り出せます。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
値の取り出しはわかりました。
ただ、どうすれば別ウィンドウの関数を呼び出すことができるのでしょうか？
コードのコメントに書きましたとおり、別ウィンドウから別ウィンドウの
Function hoge() を呼び出したいのですができません。

Comment: `hoge( )`は、無名関数の中で定義されている関数なので、外部の関数から呼び出すことはできません。あらかじめ外部の関数として定義しておくか、外部のオブジェクトの一部としておくなど（例えばvar M1= new Modal1();とかできるようにしておいてM1.hoge(1);で呼び出す）外部からアクセスできるようにしておく必要があります。

Comment: 何度も回答ありがとうございます。
無名関数で定義されている関数は、外部から呼び出しできないのですね。
質問なのですが、外部のオブジェクトの一部　というのは、グローバル関数にするということなのでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね、グローバルな関数にするのが１つ、オブジェクトの一部として関数を返すというのが１つですね。つまり`return { hoge:function(v){...}, ...};`のようにオブジェクトの一部として返す関数を作ってその返した値をローカル変数（グローバルでなくていい）にアサインしてそこから関数を使うってことです。

Comment: なるほど、ローカル変数にクラスをつけるような形でできるのですね。
試したところ、正常に動きました。
回答ありがとうございました！

Comment: BLUEPIXYさん、
コメントからはベストアンサーにできないようです。
もしよろしければ、何か回答していただければベストアンサーにさせていただこうかと思います。
よろしければ回答していただければと思います。

Comment: ずっと確証を持てないままでいるので回答にはせずにいます。自己回答、もしくはコミュニティ wiki として回答を付けることができます（そしてそれを承認できるはず）ので、解決に至った方法を書かれるといいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

グローバル化しなくとも
同じ無名関数内で書いてあげればいいような気がするけど

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。

------子ウィンドウ②（Modal2）----------
の中に同じ変数を書くということですね。
確かにそれで解決はできますが、今後変更する際に２箇所修正することに
なるので出来れば１本化したいです。
そのため、その方法を探るためにご質問させていただきました。

Comment: いや、スクリプトを一本化しない理由はなんだろうか？
と、考えていました。
<pre><script language="JavaScript">
    $(function() {
      $('#Modal1').html(data);
      $('#Modal1').modal('show');
      $('#Modal2').html(data);
      $('#Modal2').modal('show');
    
      initialize();
    
      function hoge(test){
        alert("これを実行したい");
        $("#test").val(test);
        initialize();
      }

      function initialize(){
        //初期処理
      }

      //子ウィンドウ①の関数を実行したい
      hoge(1);
    });
    </script>
</pre>

Comment: 親Viewに処理を書いて、子ウィンドウにその発火イベントを書いていくといった形でしょうか？
その形ですと、無名関数内の関数にアクセスできないと思うのですが何か方法があるのでしょうか？
無知ですいませんが、ご教授ください。

Comment: ああ、意味がわかった。
ちょっと考えてみる

Comment: BootStrapのモーダルならば、同じHTMLのDOM上に
親View、子ウィンドウ①、子ウィンドウ②、が存在して
Viewもウィンドウも、そういう概念は無いはずだから、一つの無名関数内でコントロールできるはず...と思うんだけど

そうではなくて新しい Window を開いていてそれを
親View、子ウィンドウ①、子ウィンドウ②、としているのかな？

Comment: 新しいWindowなどは開かず、全て同じHTMLのDOM上にあります。

Comment: この質問で気になったのですが、1つの無名関数でコントロールできるというのは次のどちらを指していますでしょうか？  
①-親ウィンドウ側で子ウィンドウのDOMを操作できる  
②-親ウィンドウ側の無名関数で子ウィンドウのクリックイベントも取得できる  

①でしたら既にテストしていて、出来ることは確かめています。   
②はやり方がわからないです。

Answer (score 1):

一般的には、JavaScriptならコールバック。objective-cならデリゲートと呼ばれる手法でこの手のことは解決をすると思います。（厳密にはコールバックとデリゲートは違うものですが）